# how to add a font to android application by kivy?

Tags: android, kivy

i already add some txt files in android by this path `/data/data/package-name/files/app/filefolder/file.txt`

the txt file is in the same directory with `main.py` like `/same_directory_with_main.py/filefolder/file.txt`

based on this experience, i am trying to add some custom fonts in my application.
and i makes directory exactly same way which add txt files.

part of `main.py`

```
from kivy.config import Config      
Config.set('kivy', 'default_font', [
    '/data/data/org.test.tubuc/files/app/font/NanumSquareR.ttfs',
    '/data/data/org.test.tubuc/files/app/font/NanumSquareL.ttfs',
])
```

but logcat says can't find the font path.
here the log.

```
09-24 10:47:57.506 18392 18581 I python  : ('Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is', '__main__')
09-24 10:47:57.540 18392 18581 I python  : ['/data/user/0/org.test.tubuc/files/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/data/user/0/org.test.tubuc/files/app/lib/site-python']
09-24 10:47:57.540 18392 18581 I python  : AND: Ran string
09-24 10:47:57.540 18392 18581 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
09-24 10:47:57.650 18392 18581 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 19)
09-24 10:47:57.650 18392 18581 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
09-24 10:47:57.659 18392 18581 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.test.tubuc/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_18-09-24_0.txt
09-24 10:47:57.659 18392 18581 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
09-24 10:47:57.660 18392 18581 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.2 (default, Aug 17 2018, 08:01:29) 
09-24 10:47:57.660 18392 18581 I python  : [GCC 4.9.x 20150123 (prerelease)]
09-24 10:47:57.691 18392 18581 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
09-24 10:47:57.994 18392 18581 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
09-24 10:47:58.022 18392 18581 I python  : [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
09-24 10:47:58.023 18392 18581 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
09-24 10:47:58.023 18392 18581 I python  :    File "/root/Desktop/hi/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 14, in <module>
09-24 10:47:58.024 18392 18581 I python  :    File "/root/Desktop/hi/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/tubuc/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/button.py", line 40, in <module>
09-24 10:47:58.024 18392 18581 I python  :    File "/root/Desktop/hi/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/tubuc/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/label.py", line 246, in <module>
09-24 10:47:58.024 18392 18581 I python  :    File "/root/Desktop/hi/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/tubuc/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/text/__init__.py", line 797, in <module>
09-24 10:47:58.025 18392 18581 I python  :    File "/root/Desktop/hi/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/tubuc/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/text/__init__.py", line 248, in register
09-24 10:47:58.025 18392 18581 I python  :  IOError: File /data/data/org.test.tubuc/files/app/font/NanumSquareL.ttfs not found
09-24 10:47:58.042 18392 18581 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

How can i add a font to android? thank you.

Comment: Try using relative paths rather than the absolute one, I'm not sure if the absolute path you're using will reliably work. Also, you can explore whether the files are in the place you expect using other functions in the os module.

Comment: If they are in the same folder as the main.py, the file name should be enough, no need to use the full name, and else, yeah, use relative path, or use the kivy.resource.add_folder to add a relative folder to the lookup. Also, i'm curious about the extension, don't you mean ".ttf" instead of ".ttfs"?

Comment: Thanks for the advices guys. i will try using relative paths. @Tshirtman , and yeah the extension i '.ttf'. First, i wrote the extension as a '.ttf' but IOError indicates 'ttfs' so i changed it to '.ttfs' assuming the extension is wrong. but consequently, there is no difference.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I do it with the font file at the same level as main.py

```
#main.py
import os
tools_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
icons_path = os.path.join(tools_path, 'NanumSquareL.ttfs')
```

And also on buildozer.spec include the extension ttfs

```
#buildozer.spec
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas, ttfs, json
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had an issue where I was not explicitly specifying the extensions to be included in buildozer.spec but explicitly specifying them like you said fixed the problem. I didn't need to change my main.py

Answer (score 1):

You need do these things;

1. Install your font type as .ttf
2. Put in your apk compile file. So between .buildozer and buildozer and bin and your main.py code
3. Change buildozer.spec this part: source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,**ttf** include 'ttf' in it.

[so example ascii.ttf in compile file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCfIP.png)

then going on **buildozer android debug deploy run**